# "ORA-04098: trigger is invalid and failed re-validation ORA-06512: at line

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**"ORA-04098: trigger 'SMARTNLP1.TRG_PI_RECHARGE' is invalid and failed re-validationORA-06512: at "HDFC_PI.TRG_PI_RECHARGE", line 94**

Getting Above when try to insert in ECMS_RECHARGE TABLE.

```
   IF LV_CNT > 0 THEN
         BEGIN

--              --BASIC LOYALTY POINTS CALCULATION
--              BEGIN
--                SELECT REWID, FACTOR, MULTIPLIER INTO LV_BAS_REWID, LV_BAS_FACTOR, LV_BAS_MULTIPLIER
--                FROM SMARTNLP1.VTSMLPOINTS
--                WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN EFFFROM AND EFFTO
--                  AND REWTYPE = 'B' AND TRNTYPE = 'LO'
--                  AND STATUS = 'A';
--
--                LV_POINTSEARN := ROUND((LV_AMOUNT/100) * NVL(LV_BAS_FACTOR, 0) * NVL(LV_BAS_MULTIPLIER, 0), 0);
--
--                EXCEPTION
--                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
--                BEGIN
--                  LV_POINTSEARN :=0;
--                END;
--              END;

              /*Get opening*/
              SELECT CD.PCARDID, CD.CARDBAL,LD.CARDBALANCE 
              INTO LV_PCARDID,LV_OPCMSBAL,LV_OPCMSLPOINTBAL 
              FROM SMARTNLP1.VTCMCUST CUST
                INNER JOIN SMARTNLP1.VTCMPERSN PER ON PER.CUSTID=CUST.CUSTID AND PER.PARENTFLAG='P'
                INNER JOIN SMARTNLP1.VTIMPCARD CD ON CD.CUSTCHLDID = PER.CUSTCHLDID
                INNER JOIN SMARTNLP1.VTIMLCARD LD ON LD.CARDNO= CD.CARDNO
              WHERE CUST.CRNNO = LV_FONO AND CD.CURRSTATUS < '7';



              /* Inserting into NLP table */


              INSERT INTO SMARTNLP1.ECMS_RECHARGE( BANKCODE, UTRNO, VALUEDT, VALUETM, IFSC, BPCBANKAC, FONO, CUSTIFSC, CUSTBANKAC,
                                                   AMOUNT, BRCODE, BANKNAME, CUSTBANKNM, CUSTBRCODE, CURRENCY, TRANDT, TRANTM,
                                                   CUSTREFNO1, CUSTREFNO2, AREACODE, PAYMODE, COMPCODE, DOCNO, GJAHR, STATUS,
                                                   TRANCUR, EXGRATE, CRDRFLAG, CHEQUEDT, DEPSLIPNO, DEPDT, R41LINE4551, LOYALTY_REMARKS,
                                                   LOYALTY_TRANSACTION_ID, LOYALTY_TRX_STATUS, INFO_RCVD_DT )
              SELECT :NEW.BANKCODE, :NEW.UTRNO, :NEW.VALUEDT, :NEW.VALUETM, :NEW.IFSC, :NEW.BPCBANKAC, :NEW.FONO, :NEW.CUSTIFSC,
                     :NEW.CUSTBANKAC, :NEW.AMOUNT, :NEW.BRCODE, :NEW.BANKNAME, :NEW.CUSTBANKNM, :NEW.CUSTBRCODE, :NEW.CURRENCY, :NEW.TRANDT,
                     :NEW.TRANTM, :NEW.CUSTREFNO1, :NEW.CUSTREFNO2, :NEW.AREACODE, :NEW.PAYMODE, :NEW.COMPCODE, :NEW.DOCNO, :NEW.GJAHR,
                     :NEW.STATUS, :NEW.TRANCUR, :NEW.EXGRATE, :NEW.CRDRFLAG, :NEW.CHEQUEDT, :NEW.DEPSLIPNO, :NEW.DEPDT, :NEW.R41LINE4551,
                     :NEW.LOYALTY_REMARKS, :NEW.LOYALTY_TRANSACTION_ID, :NEW.LOYALTY_TRX_STATUS, :NEW.INFO_RCVD_DT
              FROM DUAL;
```

**Getting An Error in Line No :94**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did your trigger [compile successfully](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e2100.htm)?

Comment: @astentx yes it is compile an not giving any error

Answer (score 2):

This is very basic oracle database debugging. The error just indicates that the statement cannot be run because the trigger is invalid. It does not say why the trigger is invalid. Open the trigger in sql developer and compile it, that should show you the error.
Alternative, you can also recompile the trigger using this command:

```
ALTER TRIGGER trg_pi_recharge COMPILE;
```

This will probably give you the message

```
Warning: execution completed with warning
```

To see the warnings, execute "sho err;"

```
sho err;
```

This will show you why it is failing and give you a more detailed error message.